# NetBSD/FreeBSD and TP-Link TL-WN727N: Second encounter

Tags: drivers, freebsd, netbsd

Moved from SU.
First part at  https://superuser.com/questions/975564/netbsd-and-tp-link-tl-wn727n-atheros-ar9271-or-ralink-rt5370

So, I've installed NetBSD 7 and device shown again as `ugen`(ugein, lol).

```
ugen0 at uhub4 port 8 
ugen0: Mediatek 802.11 n WLAN, rev 2.01/00, addr 2
```

Then I'm installed FreeBSD 10.2 and `ugen` again.

`usbconfig` gives me `ugen4.3: <product 0x7601 vendor 0x148f> at usbus4, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH(480Mbps) pwr=ON (90ma)`

So, what's next? Buying new dongle is a last thing, which I'll make.

Answer (score 0):

Again, `ugen0` is no interface with you can interact (W)LAN communication. Try:

```
dmesg | grep "not configured"
```

if there is a line with your USB pci & vendor id, your device is not supported. Maybe [9271 isn't supported by Freebsd](https://wiki.freebsd.org/dev/ath(4)).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I investigated that this usb dongle just doesn't have any support. 
NDIS drivers also won't work. 
No way currently. 
Thanks to all.